# python exe file crashes while launching on windows xp

Tags: python, windows, numpy, py2exe

I have a python program that used Tkinter, matplotlib, numpy.
It was builded successfully on my windows 8 host system by py2exe and running as well.
I have one system based on windows 7 where this program (builded on windows 8) working too.
But when i trying to start this program on windows xp sp3, i get error in log file with a content of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "DrawPlots.py", line 6, in <module>
File "graph_ani2.pyc", line 4, in <module>
File "numpy\__init__.pyc", line 170, in <module>
File "numpy\add_newdocs.pyc", line 13, in <module>
File "numpy\lib\__init__.pyc", line 8, in <module>
File "numpy\lib\type_check.pyc", line 11, in <module>
File "numpy\core\__init__.pyc", line 46, in <module>
File "numpy\testing\__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>
File "numpy\testing\utils.pyc", line 15, in <module>
File "tempfile.pyc", line 35, in <module>
File "random.pyc", line 885, in <module>
File "random.pyc", line 97, in __init__
File "random.pyc", line 113, in seed
  WindowsError: [Error -2146893795]
```

As i can suggest - is it problem with numpy? If yes, then how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar problem, [PyFactura issue #3](https://github.com/SistemasAgiles/pyfactura/issues/3), the solution seems to be removing `crypt32.dll` from the bundled DLLs (py2exe setup options, for more info see [aws-cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/commit/c42d98e7ed7d4b6cbede3e14aa4fde182a71863c#diff-2eeaed663bd0d25b7e608891384b7298L14)):

```python
# basic options for py2exe
opts = { 
    'py2exe': {
        'dll_excludes': ['crypt32.dll'],
        }
    }
```

You may need to exclude other specific Windows 8.1 DLL too (`API-MS-Win-Core-*.dll`)

Comment: Important: Remember to delete (or rename) the crypt32.dll file in the destination folder of py2exe's output.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this error, concretely this output:

```
WindowsError: [Error -2146893795] Provider DLL failed to initialize correctly
```

This happened at a call to `os.urandom`.
This was in a subprocess.

The bug for me was that I called `_subprocess.CreateProcess` with an `env_mapper = {'foo': 'bar'}`. The fix:

```
env_mapper = os.environ.copy()
env_mapper.update({'foo': 'bar'})
```

Note that there is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791005/windows-error-provider-dll-failed-to-initialize-correctly-on-import-of-cgi-mo).
And some discussion on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1226).
And [this related Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1384175).
All those seem to be related to `crypt32.dll` in a frozen Python app, or via py2app.